# Is there a way to refactor all variable names without respecting any scopes?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, obfuscation

I'm new to JavaScript. I have a large file of obfuscated JS code that contains a lot of functions which parameters all follow the same order.

Something like this:

```
f1 = function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) { ... c++ ... }
f2 = function (a, b, c, d) { ... c++ ... }
...
f99 = function (a, b, c) { ... c++ ... }
f100 = function (a, b) { ... }
```

Now I need to `git diff` this code with a later version of the file where the function names stay the same but the ordering in all the function declaration parameters has changed with c and d reversed:

```
f1 = function (a, b, d, c, e, f, g) { ... d++ ... }
f2 = function (a, b, d, c) { ... d++ ... }
...
f99 = function (a, b, d) { ... d++ ... }
f100 = function (a, b) { ... }
```

which caused `git diff` to spit out an output twice larger than both files with all differences like the above highlighted.

So to filter away those unnecessary lines from the diff output, I'm trying to refactor the old code to change all variables in the file with the exact name `c` to `d` and vice versa.

If I try with VSCode's `Rename Symbol` (F2), only the `c` and `d` variables in the current scope would be swapped, so I would have to repeat it for every single function in the file (f1 to f100) which would be tedious.

On the other hand if I use `Change All Occurrences` (Ctrl+F2) to, say, replace `" c"` with `" d"` it would also change partial matches such as `cat` and `dog`.

Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume that obfuscation is an automated process. Can you "re-obfuscate" the later version of the file so that `f99 = function (a, b, d) { ... d++ ... }` becomes `f99 = function (a, b, c) { ... c++ ... }` again?

Comment: The code is not mine and I don't have access to the original code for reobfuscation.

Comment: But you have access to the code that contains `f99 = function (a, b, d) { ... d++ ... }`. If you obfuscate that, don't you get `f99 = function (a, b, c) { ... c++ ... }`?

Comment: I guess, but I don't know what tool the code creator used to obfuscate the code in the first place. Would reobfuscating both versions of the code with the same tool work?

Comment: You should try it.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen I tried an online obfuscator and it significantly reduced the size of the diff, thanks!

Comment: First of all, if you want to change `c` to `d` and vice versa, you would have to change one of them to something different first, ie `c -> z   d -> c   z -> d` because otherwise you won't be able to distinguish between the "old" and the "new"  d ... Second, almost ever IDE has a seach option like "whole word only", which which will find the `c` in `c` or `foobar.c` or `c.foobar` but not in `cat`

Comment: why not just search and replace "c, d" with "d, c"? is it because it matters for the call sites too? (I assume yes, but by how much?)